# How to find duplicate subtrees

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-tree, depth-first-search

I am having trouble find the duplicate subtrees.

In the following leetcode problem 652. Find Duplicate Subtrees

Given the root of a binary tree, return all duplicate subtrees. For each kind of duplicate subtrees, you only need to return the root node of any one of them. Two trees are duplicate if they have the same structure with the same node values.

My implementation is as follows:

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.duplicates = []
    
    def isSameSubtree(self, left, right):
        if left is None or right is None:
            return True
        elif left is None:
            return False
        elif right is None:
            return False
        
        if left.val != right.val:
            return False
        
        return self.isSameSubtree(left.left, right.left) or \
               self.isSameSubtree(left.right, right.right)
    
    def helper(self, node):
        if node is None:
            return node
        
        left = self.helper(node.left)
        right = self.helper(node.right)
        
        if self.isSameSubtree(left, right):
            self.duplicates.append(left)
            return left
        
    def findDuplicateSubtrees(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> List[Optional[TreeNode]]:
        self.helper(root)
        return self.duplicates
```

My thought process was that I would check both left and right subtrees by passing each parent node of each subtree into `isSameSubtree` method. Problem is I don't feel like I am doing any of this correctly. What I want is to analyze both left and right subtrees by doing what I am doing in my helper function and when I go back up the stack and find a parent node with both left and right subtrees that match return that parent node.

Comment: That is a wonderful opportunity to review (or learn about) [Merkle Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree).  The idea is that you can traverse your tree just once, and at each node note the hash of the corresponding subtree, testing each time if you've already seen that hash.

Comment: I don't understand your algorithm. It makes little sense. For instance, `helper` is doomed to *always* return `None`. You need to go back to the drawing table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that is related to [Merkle Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree). In fact, we can define a helper function (no need to modify the `Node` or `Tree` class, although of course that is also a possibility if preferred) as follow:

```py
def sign(t):
    """depth-first iterator; for each node, yield (hash, node) tuple"""
    hashes = (hash(t.data), )
    for c in t.children or []:
        for h, n in sign(c):
            yield h, n
            hashes = hashes + (h, )
    yield hash(hashes), t
```

Usage example, on a simplistic `Node` structure:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, children=None):
        self.data = data
        self.children = children
    
    def __repr__(self):
        if self.children:
            return f'{self.data}:{self.children}'
        return str(self.data)
```

Then, for example:

```py
t = Node('a', (Node('b', (Node('c'), Node('d'))), (Node('b', (Node('c'), Node('d'))))))

>>> t
a:(b:(c, d), b:(c, d))

>>> list(sign(t))
[(-8022040514780200320, c),
 (-5838450013443269355, d),
 (-6612941109014678970, b:(c, d)),
 (-8022040514780200320, c),
 (-5838450013443269355, d),
 (-6612941109014678970, b:(c, d)),
 (-3704690573080571573, a:(b:(c, d), b:(c, d)))]
```

As you can see, the subtrees `Node('d')` all have the same fingerprint: `-5838450013443269355`, and all `b:(c, d)` nodes have `-6612941109014678970` (Note: actual numerical values will depend on your `PYTHONHASHSEED`, the values given here are just examples). One very nice property of this is to be very lightweight, it is `O[n]` for `n` nodes (there are no needlessly repeated `hash` computations).

From there, it is trivial to detect repeated subtrees:

```py
seen = set()
for h, c in sign(t):
    if h in seen:
        print(f'duplicate: {c}')
    seen.add(h)

# on the example tree above, this prints:
# duplicate: c
# duplicate: d
# duplicate: b:(c, d)
```

Note, if you are allowed to modify your `Node` structure, then the solution is even simpler: add this to your `Node` structure:

```py
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.data, tuple(hash(c) for c in self.children or [])))
    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Node) and self.data == other.data and self.children == other.children
```

You can then compute the hash of any `Node` and compare for equality between nodes that have the same hash. In practice, your duplicate detection becomes:

```py
def dupes(t, seen=None):
    if seen is None:
        seen = set()
    for c in t.children or []:
        yield from dupes(c, seen)
    if t in seen:
        yield t
    else:
        seen.add(t)
```

Example:

```py
>>> list(dupes(t))
[c, d, b:(c, d)]
```

Comment: I am doing the LeetCode challenge of the Hash Module. it asks me the same thing: find the duplicate sub_trees. But it gives me one linear array to represent the binary tree. For example:
root = [1,2,3,4,None,2,4,None,None,4]

I am really confused. How can I build the binary-tree from this vector?

Here is the link to the challenge:
https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/hash-table/185/hash_table_design_the_key/1128/